# Why is this equation not centered?

Tags: center

Although there is already at least one question with the same title, I believe that none correspond to the same problem.

The following code snippet is where the problem occurs: the second equation does not appear centered. You can see the result in the screenshot that I show below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[tmargin=28mm,bmargin=28mm,lmargin=28mm,rmargin=28mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,amssymb,epsfig,amstext,amsthm,mathpazo, xfp, latexsym}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{3.0.10}
    \fcolorbox{gray}{gray!10}{$ \displaystyle
        \begin{split}
            x_{42} &\equiv \dfrac{(x_{41} y_{11} - x_{11} y_{41})(y_{11} - y_{41})}{(x_{11} - x_{41})^2 + (y_{11} - y_{41})^2}\\
            y_{42} &\equiv \dfrac{(x_{41} y_{11} - x_{11} y_{41})(x_{41} - x_{11})}{(x_{11} - x_{41})^2 + (y_{11} - y_{41})^2}
        \end{split}$}
\end{equation}
\\
after 3 iterations and very long algebraic simplifications, we get:
\\
\begin{equation}\label{3.0.11}
    \fcolorbox{gray}{gray!10}{$ \displaystyle
    \begin{split}
    s_{14}^2 = & \frac{(x_{21} y_{31} - x_{31} y_{21})^2}{(x_{31} - x_{21})^2 + (y_{31} - y_{21})^2} \cdot\\
    \cdot & \frac{(x_{31} y_{41} - x_{41} y_{31})^2}{(x_{41} - x_{31})^2 + (y_{41} - y_{31})^2} \cdot \\
    \cdot & \frac{1}{\left(x_{21}^2 + y_{21}^2\right) \left(x_{31}^2 + y_{31}^2\right)\left(x_{41}^2 + y_{41}^2\right)} \cdot \\
    \cdot & \frac{1}{(x_{21} - x_{11})^2 + (y_{21} - y_{11})^2}\cdot\\
    \cdot & \frac{\lambda_4'^2}{(x_{11} - x_{41})^2 + (y_{11} - y_{41})^2}
    \end{split}$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

\

[image]

**EDIT 1 __________________________________________________________________**

I had omitted several packages; now I include them all. But I don't think that is the problem, because in the document I have a lot of similar equations and this problem is not presented; it is something strange.

Obviously, I could fix it manually, but I would like to know why this is happening.

Thanks, David Carlisle, for your responses; I have already deleted the epsfig pachage; I don't really remember why I had included it anymore. I include the packages following an example or recommendation, but I do not know how they work or the problems that they can, apart from the consumption of resources, due to possible incompatibilities. Therefore, any suggestion in this regard will always be well received.

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
    \usepackage[tmargin=28mm,bmargin=28mm,lmargin=28mm,rmargin=28mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,amssymb,amstext,amsthm,mathpazo, xfp, latexsym}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage[usenames]{color}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \usepackage{tikz, ifthen, bclogo}
    \usepackage{pst-poly}
    \usepackage{pst-all}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals,calc} \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,patterns,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes,trees}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
    \usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
    \usepackage{latexsym, graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage[thicklines, makeroom]{cancel}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \usepackage{stmaryrd, scalerel, stackengine}
    \usepackage{pifont}
    \usepackage{calligra}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{underoverlap}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{etoolbox} %Definition of bcancelto
    
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}\label{3.0.10}
    \fcolorbox{gray}{gray!10}{$ \displaystyle
    \begin{split}
        x_{42} &\equiv \dfrac{(x_{41} y_{11} - x_{11} y_{41})(y_{11} - y_{41})} 
        {(x_{11} - x_{41})^2 + (y_{11} - y_{41})^2}\\
        y_{42} &\equiv \dfrac{(x_{41} y_{11} - x_{11} y_{41})(x_{41} - x_{11})} 
        {(x_{11} - x_{41})^2 + (y_{11} - y_{41})^2}
    \end{split}$}
  \end{equation}
  
after 3 iterations and very long algebraic simplifications, we get:\\

    \begin{equation}\label{3.0.11}
      \fcolorbox{gray}{gray!10}{$ \displaystyle
        \begin{split}
            s_{14}^2 = & \frac{(x_{21} y_{31} - x_{31} y_{21})^2}{(x_{31} - x_{21})^2 
            + (y_{31} - y_{21})^2} \cdot\\
            \cdot & \frac{(x_{31} y_{41} - x_{41} y_{31})^2}{(x_{41} - x_{31})^2 + 
             (y_{41} - y_{31})^2} \cdot \\
              \cdot & \frac{1}{\left(x_{21}^2 + y_{21}^2\right) \left(x_{31}^2 + 
             y_{31}^2\right)\left(x_{41}^2 + y_{41}^2\right)} \cdot \\
            \cdot & \frac{1}{(x_{21} - x_{11})^2 + (y_{21} - y_{11})^2}\cdot\\
            \cdot & \frac{\lambda_4'^2}{(x_{11} - x_{41})^2 + (y_{11} - 
             y_{41})^2}
      \end{split}$}
     \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: the example posted gives the error `! Undefined control sequence.
l.6     \fcolorbox`

Comment: If you add a package to define fcolorbox amsmath warns you `Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use `split' here;`  `split ` is a vertical display construct you can not use it in inline math mode

Comment: unrelated but don't use the `epsfig` package unless you have a requirement to emulate documents written before 1994.

Comment: your added example has dozens of unrelated packages. Is your editor really saving files in latin1 (the files are always UTF-8 when posted to this site) so you probably should delete  `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`  You probably don't want `times` either: use newtxtext to get a times-like font, don't load `color` if loading `xcolor`, don't load `amsmath` if loading `mathtools`, don't specify mathtools twice, are you really using pstricks and tikz at the same time?

Comment: David, without \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} I get error message using \calligra font. If I delete times package the number of pages increases, so, I better keep it. And so on,,, The only package I must delete is the duplicate of mathtools.

Comment: the input encoding is unrelated to fonts. `times` is a very old package aiming for the fonts available on a 1980s apple laser writer, it really is not recommended now. loading color and amsmath when you are loading xcolor and mathtools is not harmful it just makes no difference at al

Answer (score 6):

Don't ignore warnings!

You get an error that `\fcolorbox` is undefined so add `xcolor` package

You get a warning to use `aligned` not `split`, so change `split` to `aligned`

You get a warning about badness 10000 from the mis-placed `\\`  so delete those, then

Also use `&=` not `=&` (or use `={}&` if you need alignment on the right of the =)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[tmargin=28mm,bmargin=28mm,lmargin=28mm,rmargin=28mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,amssymb,epsfig,amstext,amsthm,mathpazo, xfp, latexsym,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{3.0.10}
    \fcolorbox{gray}{gray!10}{$
        \begin{aligned}
            x_{42} &\equiv \dfrac{(x_{41} y_{11} - x_{11} y_{41})(y_{11} - y_{41})}{(x_{11} - x_{41})^2 + (y_{11} - y_{41})^2}\\
            y_{42} &\equiv \dfrac{(x_{41} y_{11} - x_{11} y_{41})(x_{41} - x_{11})}{(x_{11} - x_{41})^2 + (y_{11} - y_{41})^2}
        \end{aligned}$}
\end{equation}
after 3 iterations and very long algebraic simplifications, we get:
\begin{equation}\label{3.0.11}
    \fcolorbox{gray}{gray!10}{$
    \begin{aligned}
    s_{14}^2 &= \frac{(x_{21} y_{31} - x_{31} y_{21})^2}{(x_{31} - x_{21})^2 + (y_{31} - y_{21})^2} \cdot\\
    &\qquad \cdot  \frac{(x_{31} y_{41} - x_{41} y_{31})^2}{(x_{41} - x_{31})^2 + (y_{41} - y_{31})^2} \cdot \\
    &\qquad \cdot  \frac{1}{\left(x_{21}^2 + y_{21}^2\right) \left(x_{31}^2 + y_{31}^2\right)\left(x_{41}^2 + y_{41}^2\right)} \cdot \\
    &\qquad \cdot  \frac{1}{(x_{21} - x_{11})^2 + (y_{21} - y_{11})^2}\cdot\\
    &\qquad \cdot  \frac{\lambda_4'^2}{(x_{11} - x_{41})^2 + (y_{11} - y_{41})^2}
    \end{aligned}$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a `{} ` missing between `=&`

Comment: @daleif I'll use `&=` thanks

Comment: Then the alignment is strange

Comment: not if you do same with `&\cdot`

Comment: Especially if you do that, hadn't noticed the cdot alignment, IMO they should not be aligned under =, but past it. But the again most 8f use does not use the double cdot either.

Comment: @daleif yes actually as a wrapped long equation I'd normally use `\quad` at start of wrapped lines,

Comment: That's where I always use the right alignment and the `{}` trick. Saves a lot of typing.

Comment: @daleif quad didn't look enough went for qquad in the end

Comment: I don't get any message error!

Comment: @JesúsÁlvarezLobo if you use the code you posted you will get the error that `\fcolorbox` is not defined. The others are warnings not errors but they still explain what is wrong.

Comment: This depends on the taste of each one; Personally, I like it better how I have done it, that is, with the expressions aligned vertically on the left. As for the double cdot, I think it is useful to indicate that it is the same expression, which could be confusing due to the line break.

Comment: I still don't understand what is preventing the second equation from centering. I had to fix it (in an inelegant way) by adding \hspace (6ex)

Comment: for alignment if you use `=&` you should use `={}&` to get correct spacing around the = as your image shows you lose the spacing otherwise. Doubling the operator on a line break is standard in Russian typography but rare elsewhere (and so rather confusing)  The horizontal positioning is arbitrary as `split` can not work there so the measurement is wrong, if you use `aligned` which is designed for that use it gets measured its natural size. @JesúsÁlvarezLobo